# R Shiny: How to write loop for observeEvent

Tags: r, loops, shiny, lapply

I have the following code. Is there any way to write it in a loop or vectorized statement like lapply? In my real code, I have even more brushes so this will be pretty helpful. Thanks.

Ignore this line. Just need to add some more texts.

```
observeEvent(input$brush_1,{
  Res=brushedPoints(D(),input$brush_1,allRows = TRUE)
  vals$keeprows = Res$selected_
  })

observeEvent(input$brush_2,{
  Res=brushedPoints(D(),input$brush_2,allRows = TRUE)
  vals$keeprows = Res$selected_

})

observeEvent(input$brush_3,{
  Res=brushedPoints(D(),input$brush_3,allRows = TRUE)
  vals$keeprows = Res$selected_

})

observeEvent(input$brush_4,{
  Res=brushedPoints(D(),input$brush_4,allRows = TRUE)
  vals$keeprows = Res$selected_

})

observeEvent(input$brush_5,{
  Res=brushedPoints(D(),input$brush_5,allRows = TRUE)
  vals$keeprows = Res$selected_

})

observeEvent(input$brush_6,{
  Res=brushedPoints(D(),input$brush_6,allRows = TRUE)
  vals$keeprows = Res$selected_

})

observeEvent(input$brush_7,{
  Res=brushedPoints(D(),input$brush_7,allRows = TRUE)
  vals$keeprows = Res$selected_

})

observeEvent(input$brush_8,{
  Res=brushedPoints(D(),input$brush_8,allRows = TRUE)
  vals$keeprows = Res$selected_

})

observeEvent(input$brush_9,{
  Res=brushedPoints(D(),input$brush_9,allRows = TRUE)
  vals$keeprows = Res$selected_

})

observeEvent(input$brush_10,{
  Res=brushedPoints(D(),input$brush_10,allRows = TRUE)
  vals$keeprows = Res$selected_

})

observeEvent(input$brush_11,{
  Res=brushedPoints(D(),input$brush_11,allRows = TRUE)
  vals$keeprows = Res$selected_

})

observeEvent(input$brush_12,{
  Res=brushedPoints(D(),input$brush_12,allRows = TRUE)
  vals$keeprows = Res$selected_

})
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`observeEvent` works great in `lapply` :

```
library("shiny")
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 6,
      lapply(
        X = 1:6,
        FUN = function(i) {
          sliderInput(inputId = paste0("d", i), label = i, min = 0, max = 10, value = i)
        }
      )
    ),
    column(
      width = 6,
      verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "test")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output){

  vals <- reactiveValues()

  lapply(
    X = 1:6,
    FUN = function(i){
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("d", i)]], {
        vals[[paste0("slider", i)]] <- input[[paste0("d", i)]]
      })
    }
  )

  output$test <- renderPrint({
    reactiveValuesToList(vals)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**EDIT** : for previous version of shiny, use this in server (add `assign`) :

```
lapply(
  X = 1:6,
  FUN = function(i){
    assign(
      paste0("obs", i),
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("d", i)]], {
        vals[[paste0("slider", i)]] <- input[[paste0("d", i)]]
      })
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: I found that this code works in shiny_0.14.1(windows 7) but not in shiny_0.13.1(Redhat). Do you think it's related to packages versions or operation systems?

Comment: In shiny_0.13.1(Redhat, R version 3.1.3 ), the `lapply` works for the `sliderInput`s but not for `observeEvent`s.

Comment: I don't have this specific version, I've tested with shiny 0.13.2 (R 3.2.0, redhat) it works, and with shiny 0.12.2 (R 3.0.2, redhat) it doesn't work, but with my edit it works.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to `for` loop, which works in all versions.

Comment: Just tested -- lapply does work great where for loops seem to fail. Must have something to do with the protected function environment of lapply.

Comment: Spent a full way circling around this. For me, for loops also fail, but lapply works. Thanks, @Taylor White