# R shiny - save chosen values in selectInput

Tags: jquery, r, shiny

I have 10 'Edit' actionButtons. On each 'Edit' action buttons appears three selectInputs. After I click on 'Save' button below selectInputs, I want to remember selected values. If i go to row 2 -> click 'Edit' -> select values -> click 'Save' and go back to row 1, it does not remember previously selected values in row 1.

So I want to have two actions on 'Save' button namely:

- store selected values for given 'Row' (so when i click again on the same Edit button I will see previously selected values)
- make all selectInputs disapear after i click on save button

  library(shiny)

  ```
  ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

     titlePanel("Update Select Inputs"),

        mainPanel(
          tags$head(tags$script(HTML("$(document).on('click', '.needed', function () {
                               Shiny.onInputChange('last_btn',this.id);
                                     });"))),
          column(width = 6,
           uiOutput('ValuesAndButtons')),
           column(width = 6,uiOutput('Details'))
        )
     )
  )

  server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$ValuesAndButtons <- renderUI({

        lapply(
          c(1:10),
          function(i){
            fluidRow(
              column(
                width = 4,
                tags$span(i)
              ),
              column(
                width = 3,
                tags$button(
                  type = "button",
                  id = paste0('ActionButton', i),
                  class="btn action-button needed",
                  "Edit"
                )
              )
            )
          }
        )
    })

    output$Details <- renderUI ({

      req(input$last_btn)

      fluidRow(
        lapply(
          c(1:3),
          function(i){
            fluidRow(
              fluidRow(
                column(
                  width = 5,
                  tags$span(i)
                ),

                column(
                  width = 5,
                  selectInput(
                    paste0("Details", i), 
                    label = NULL, 
                    choices = c("","a","b","c"),
                    selected = ""

                  )
                )
              )
            )

          }),
        fluidRow(
          tags$button(
            type = "button",
            id = "Save",
            class = "btn action-button",
            href = "#",
            "Save"
          )
        )
      )
    })

  })

  # Run the application 
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
  ```

Comment: After click on 'save' actionButton I want to update selected values in all selectInputs - they should display last selected values before 'save'. Basically I have many actionButtons (called 'mainButtonX') on which show few selectInputs and additional 'Save' Button. When I click on mainButtonX and select some values in selectInputs and click on another mainButton and go back again my selected values are null - it does not dynamically update or update on save button as I wish it to behave like that.

Comment: I updated my question and code.

Comment: You want to store values some where  or simply hide it and show?

Comment: I want to store selected values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by storing values into `reactivevValues` values stored onlyfor one `session`

```
library(shinyjs) # needed for hide and show
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Update Select Inputs"),

  mainPanel(
    useShinyjs(),
    tags$head(tags$script(HTML("$(document).on('click', '.needed', function () {
                               Shiny.onInputChange('last_btn',this.id);
                               });"))),
        column(width = 6,
               uiOutput('ValuesAndButtons')),
    column(width = 6,hidden(wellPanel(id="det",
                                      lapply(1:3,function(i){
                                        fluidRow(
                                          selectInput(
                                            paste0("Details", i), 
                                            label = i, 
                                            choices = c("","a","b","c"),
                                            selected = ""

                                          )
                                        )

                                      }),
                                      fluidRow(
                                        actionButton("Save","Save")
                                      )
    ))
    ))
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  saved_values=reactiveValues(data=NULL)

  output$ValuesAndButtons <- renderUI({

    lapply(1:10,function(i){
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 4,
          tags$span(i)
        ),
        column(
          width = 3,
          actionButton(paste0('ActionButton', i),"Edit",class="needed"  )
        )
      )
    }
    )
  })
  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$last_btn)){
      observeEvent(input[[input$last_btn]],{
        shinyjs::show("det")
      }
                   )

    }

  })
  observeEvent(input$last_btn,{

    ll<-saved_values[[input$last_btn]]
    shinyjs::show("det")

    if(!is.null(ll) ){

      for(i in 1:length(ll)){
        updateSelectInput(session = session,inputId = names(ll)[[i]],selected = ll[[i]])

      }
    }else{
      shinyjs::reset("det")
    }

  })


  observeEvent(input$Save,{

    saved_values[[input$last_btn]]=lapply(names(input)[which(substring(names(input),1,7)=="Details")],function(i){
      input[[ i]]
    })
    names(saved_values[[input$last_btn]])=names(input)[which(substring(names(input),1,7)=="Details")]
    shinyjs::hide("det")
  })


})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Error in <Anonymous>: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘reset’ for signature ‘"character"’; when I add shinyjs::reset() nothing shows up when I push 'Edit' button

Comment: try to change on `shinyjs::reset`, do you have library shinyjs?

Comment: you have useShinyjs(), in UI?

Comment: Updated my comment before your answer. I have it, version 0.6

Comment: Ok, now it works - I had to restart R. Thanks a looot! Would it be possible to click on the same Edit button after Save? Now when you click on 'Save' (row 1) and you want to push 'Edit' in row1 again, nothing shows up.

Comment: Added but its may be not best way

Comment: Is it possible to fill all select Inputs with what you chosen on first row? (so if i fill select Inputs and click on save, then choose row 2 and I will see the same values in select Inputs as in row 1)

Comment: Yes.you can simply remove reset("det")

Comment: But I want to fill select Inputs only when first row is filled. And by the way shinyjs::show() and updateSelectInput does not seem to work properly. It seems like updateSelectInput updates after show and it does not show any values (but as I print it in console, there are proper values as selected). How can I fix it? I generete "det" in server.R