# Selecting data in shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, subset

I want a shinyApp that creates a new dataframe with values selected from another one alredy loaded.

I've tried building it according to some post i've seen here but still couldn't figure it out.

Here's the df:

```
Names,ID
Adam,1234
Smith,4321
Frank,1111
```

Here is my code:

```
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
#dataframe
names <- c("Adam", "Smith", "Frank")
id <- c(1234, 4321, 1111)
data <- data.table(names, id)

#empty dataframe
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 0))
x <- c("names", "id")
colnames(df) <- x

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("names",
              "Names:",
              c("Search here...",
                data$names)),
  dataTableOutput("tabela")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df_subset <- reactive({
    df <- subset(data, names == input$names)
    return(df)
  })
  
output$tabela <- renderDataTable({df_subset()}) 

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I want the user to select the names while visualizing them, and them click on a action button (that i'll work on later) to run a script over that new dataframe.

When i select the first name it selects that value to the table, but overwrites it when i select another one.

Here is what it should look like:

> [Select screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB4a8.png)
>
> [After selecting one name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rR45.png)
>
> [After selecting a second name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9haD.png)

And so on, so they could select as many as they want.
Can someone help me out?
Thank you

Comment: When  you're subsetting `df`, the column name being used is incorrect - it should be `names` isntead of `nomes`. Same for the `selectInput` argument. Also, why do you want an empty df, you can subset `data` directly as a reactive object and display that. Displaying does not change `data` itself.

Comment: thank you! I've solved that. but still can't run the example without the overwriting problem. i've edited the code and you can see what i meant.

Answer (score 0):

Its a naming mistake that gave your error. Below is the working example.  But, your q is still not clear, what do you mean by subsetting empty data frame ? Just wanted to let you know if in case you are not aware. When you are using `renderDataTable`, the search box automatically subsets based on what you type. For instance, if you type `Adam` all the rows with name adam will be automatically subsetted.

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

names <- c("Adam", "Smith", "Frank")
id <- c(1234, 4321, 1111)
data <- data.table(names, id)

ui <- fluidPage(selectInput("name",
                            "Names",
                            choices = unique(data$names)),

                dataTableOutput("table"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #creating empty dataframe to be subsetted
  df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 0))
  x <- c("names", "id")
  colnames(df) <- x

  df_subset <- reactive({
    a <- subset(df, names == input$name)
    return(a)
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    df_subset()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I need that the user can select the names from dataframe and visualize it while doing so.
So what he is doing basicly is filtering the data from the other table. I hope i've made myself clear. I'm going to edit to a smaller version and you could see better what i meant.

Answer (score 0):

The dataframe `data` is not being overwritten - it's being "actively" subset based on  the input - if that makes sense. The rendered `dataTableOutput` is changing which is the expected behaviour.

Additionally, you do not need to have a reactive `df_subset`, the following code should work just fine:

**CODE**

```
library(data.table)
library(shiny)

names <- c("Adam", "Smith", "Frank")
id <- c(1234, 4321, 1111)
data <- data.table(names, id)
rm(names, id)

ui <- fluidPage(      
  fluidRow(
    column(12,
           h2("Original Table"),
           dataTableOutput("tabela")
           )
    ),
  fluidRow(
    column(8, 
           h2("Select Names for new table"),
           selectInput(inputId = "names", label = "Select Name", 
                       choices = data$names, multiple = T))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(12, 
           h2("Subset Table"),
           dataTableOutput("tabelb"))
  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tabela <- renderDataTable({return(data)})
  output$tabelb <- renderDataTable({return(data[ names %in% input$names])})       
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: Output]

Look at the answers here: [R shiny - save chosen values in selectInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171222/r-shiny-save-chosen-values-in-selectinput), you may want to save `reactiveValues` for a session - seems more elegant.

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for the answer.
But i've just tried the code you gave and it didn't work out as the way i was expecting.

I need that the to add the names i select from the options to the dataframe "df", that is being printed. For example, selecting the first name will print only the first. when i select a second name it shows the previous and the other one i selected.

Comment: Got it, you want to see two tables then, not one. And need two output objects.

Comment: I think so! I've uploaded some images and i think it will clarify it even more

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! 
Futhermore i'd like to ask you these questions:
>First: when selecting the names they keep filling the select box. isn't there a way for them to disappear? Because the original df i'll work on has thousands of names, so it could get a little bit confusing after selecting a huge amount of names.
>Second: where's this new subset df being saved to? I'll later run a script over that df. For example: dim(subsettable)

Comment: For the first part, you should look into `reactiveValues` to store all selected options. For example, you could select 5 names and then click "save" to store them to the `reactiveValues` object (`tableb` here). In the current code, the subset data is only being displayed, not saved. you could add  `downloadButton` or `actionButton` object which will write the current form of `tableb` to a file. Look up these functions on Shiny website - lots of examples on generating reports that match what you're looking for.

Comment: and how could i save that value from tableb?

Comment: save it to .rda/.rds, write directly to a file using `fwrite` etc. There are enough examples of saving/reporting data in Shiny on SO.

Comment: no, i mean...
I want to save it to a dataframe so i could work on it!