# Remember and show all user input in an R Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

In an R Shiny app, is there a way to remember all user inputs and print out the results?

The current app will allow the user to upload a .csv data file, after which they can go to one of the probability tabs and enter new data information. This will give a new predicted probability for each new entry.

As an example, if the user enters a new value for "FIB-4", they will get the output "New FIB-4 value is: [value], and new predicted values are [predicted probability] each time the user submits a new value for FIB-4 in addition to all previous entries. So, the main panel will show for new FIB-4 values say 4 and 10:

"New FIB-4 value is: 4, and new predicted values are 0.48"

"New FIB-4 value is: 10, and new predicted values are 0.58"

I saw from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171222/r-shiny-save-chosen-values-in-selectinput) and [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/mLKhPUmAiAk) that `reactiveValue` may be the way to go, but do I need to have an "order" counter to save all the values in order?

```
ui<-navbarPage("R268 - Fibroscan analysis (Program adapted from Subhasish code) ",
           tabPanel("Data Import",
                    sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel( fileInput("file","Upload your CSV",multiple = FALSE),
                                                tags$hr(),
                                                h5(helpText("Select the read.table parameters below")),
                                                checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Header', value = FALSE),
                                                checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors", "stringAsFactors", FALSE),
                                                radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', 
                                                             choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''), selected = ',')
                    ),
                    mainPanel(uiOutput("tb1"))
                    ) ),
 tabPanel("Probability of discordance between fibroscan and biopsy",
                    sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel( 
                      numericInput("fib4", "Enter new FIB-4 value:", 1.72, min = 0, max = 20),

                      actionButton("update2", "Update")
                    ),
                    mainPanel(helpText("The probability of discordance between Fibroscan and biopsy is: "),
                              verbatimTextOutput("print_prob2"))
                    ) )
)
server<-function(input,output) { 

   data <- reactive({
   file1 <- input$file
   req(file1) 
   read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)
 })
output$table <- renderTable({
     if(is.null(data())){return ()}
     data()
})
output$tb1 <- renderUI({
     tableOutput("table")
})
prob_discFibBiop<-eventReactive(input$update2,{
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    rm(list = ls())
    f<-data()

    subdat <- f[,c("Dis.Fibrosis.FS.vs.Bx..0.no.discordance..1.Results.discordant..Adv_vs_NonAdv","Fib4")]
    subdat <- subdat[complete.cases(subdat),]

    library(caret)
    form <- sprintf("%s~%s","Dis.Fibrosis.FS.vs.Bx..0.no.discordance..1.Results.discordant..Adv_vs_NonAdv",c("Fib4"))

    logreg <-glm(as.formula(form),family=binomial(),data=subdat)
    pred <- predict(logreg, newdata=data.frame(Fib4 = input$fib4),type="response")
    pred <- round(pred, 2); pred.output <- cbind(pred,1-pred); colnames(pred.output) <- c("Discordant","No discordance")
    return(pred.output)
 })

output$print_prob2 <- renderPrint({

  print.output <- paste0("New FIB-4 input: ", input$fib4, " will result in ", prob_discFibBiop())
  print(print.output)
})
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: I tried to analyze your app but your code is not does not dynamically for .csv inputs.
`Dis.Fibrosis.FS.vs.Bx..0.no.discordance..1.Results.discordant..Adv_vs_NonAdv"` This should not a column name in a shiny app. Provide some sample data on github or so, than I might help you.

Comment: Sorry! I have uploaded a sample data here: https://github.com/jwyu22/Data.git

Comment: I get undefined columns selected :-(

Comment: You may have to select "Header" and "stringAsFactors" checkbox when you upload the data. I'm sorry - I have not made this adaptable to other situations (yet).