# Shiny - observe() triggered by dynamicaly generated inputs

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny code that generates selectInputs and each of those selectInput generate the plot title. The problem is that I don't know how to trigger an observe() with dynamically generated buttons. The workaround I used was to write on the code the input[[]] trigger for each selectInput to start the observe. Is it possible to trigger the observe() from all generated inputs?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic selectInput"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItemOutput("menuitem")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    numericInput("graph_tytle_num","Number of Graph Title elements",value = 1,min = 1,max = 10),
    uiOutput("graph_title"),
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$menuitem <- renderMenu({
    menuItem("Menu item", icon = icon("calendar"))
  })


  #elements of graphic titles  
  output$graph_title <- renderUI({
    buttons <- as.list(1:input$graph_tytle_num)
    buttons <- lapply(buttons, function(i)

      column(3,
        selectInput(inputId = paste0("title_element",i),
                    label = paste("Title element",i),
                    choices = paste0(LETTERS[i],seq(1,i*2)),
                    selected = 1)
      )
    )
  })


  observe({

    #Can this observe be triggerd by the dynamicaly generate selectInput?
    #In this the observe is only triggered with the first 3 selectInput
    input[[paste0("title_element",1)]]
    input[[paste0("title_element",2)]]
    input[[paste0("title_element",3)]]


    isolate({ #I dont want to have the numericInput input$graph_tytle_num to be a trigger

      #Create the graph title
      title <- c()
      for(i in 1:input[["graph_tytle_num"]]){
        title <- paste(title,input[[paste0("title_element",i)]])
      }

      output$plot <-renderPlot({hist(rnorm(100,4,1),
                                     breaks = 10,
                                     main = title)})
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is answer was very useful to me, e.g. use |`observeEvent( reactiveValuesToList(input) , {print("some currently defined input has changed")})` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41031584/collect-all-user-inputs-throughout-the-shiny-app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not an expert in Shiny, but It seems that it's not possible to trigger one observer with dynamically generated inputs. My workaround is based on this answer:  [R shiny - last clicked button id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40168801/r-shiny-last-clicked-button-id).

The idea is to keep track of the last selection on all the dynamicallygenerated `selectInput`'s using a JavaScript function. That function will update a shiny input variable with the id of the last `selectedInput` used.

Below is you code modified with the solution. Please note that because we need to distinguish between the dynamically generated `selectInput`'s and others `selectInput`'s, I wrapped those `selectInput`'s in a `div` with a dummy class. The JavaScript function will only react to those that are inside that `div`. Also, the functions will generate a random number inside the JavaScript function to make the observer react to changes in the same `selectInput`.

```R
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic selectInput"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItemOutput("menuitem")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    # keep track of the last selection on all selectInput created dynamically
    tags$script("$(document).on('change', '.dynamicSI select', function () {
                              Shiny.onInputChange('lastSelectId',this.id);
                              // to report changes on the same selectInput
                              Shiny.onInputChange('lastSelect', Math.random());
                             });"),            
    numericInput("graph_tytle_num","Number of Graph Title elements",value = 1,min = 1,max = 10),
    uiOutput("graph_title"),
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$menuitem <- renderMenu({
    menuItem("Menu item", icon = icon("calendar"))
  })

  #elements of graphic titles  
  output$graph_title <- renderUI({
    buttons <- as.list(1:input$graph_tytle_num)
    # use a div with class = "dynamicSI" to distinguish from other selectInput's
    div( class = "dynamicSI",
      lapply(buttons, function(i)
        column(3,
          selectInput(inputId = paste0("title_element",i),
                      label = paste("Title element",i),
                      choices = paste0(LETTERS[i],seq(1,i*2)),
                      selected = 1)
        )
      )
    )
  })

  # react to changes in dynamically generated selectInput's
  observe({
    input$lastSelect

    if (!is.null(input$lastSelectId)) {
      cat("lastSelectId:", input$lastSelectId, "\n")
      cat("Selection:", input[[input$lastSelectId]], "\n\n")
    }

    isolate({ #I dont want to have the numericInput input$graph_tytle_num to be a trigger
      #Create the graph title
      title <- c()
      for(i in 1:input[["graph_tytle_num"]]){
        title <- paste(title,input[[paste0("title_element",i)]])
      }

      output$plot <-renderPlot({hist(rnorm(100,4,1),
                                     breaks = 10,
                                     main = title)})
    })

  })  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Finally, you can extend this approach to any other Shiny widget just by modifying the selector on the JavaScript function. For instance, if you want to have `actionButton`'s you can change the `event` and the `selector` from `change` and `select` to `click` and `button`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't know javaScrip lang though. Where can I learn other options for the [event] and the [selector]. What if I want the [event] to be a [checkbox] or a [checkboxGroup]?

Comment: Old question, but nevertheless it is possible to trigger one observer with dynamically generated inputs. Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51622007/9841389).

Comment: Hi, this code is very useful, I am trying to do the same thing but with different kind of inputs (selectInput / numericInput / radioButtons / dateInput), so if i change      
 '.dynamicSI select' to '.dynamicSI :input' then it will catch the changes in selectInput and numericInput but not in the second two, how can i catch changes in all kind of inputs with dynamicSI class?

Comment: @Basel.D It should work but maybe there is something missing. Open a new question with you code using the radio buttons  and date input, maybe someone can spot the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Geovany  , i will open a new question with my example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61475419/shiny-dynamically-generated-inputs