# R Shiny: nested observe functions

Tags: r, shiny

For the sample data set `mtcars`, we want to use `"cyl","am","carb","gear"` to be the candidate filters(selectInput widgets). Users should be able to select the filter they want.

And for each filter picked, there is an '(un)select all' button associated with it.

My issue is, since the number of filters is not fixed, so the loop statement to generate the `observeEvent` statements has to be in another `observe` function.

Please run the following reproducible code.

Any suggestions to make the '(un)select all' botton work? thanks.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  R = mtcars[,c("cyl","am","carb","gear")]

  output$FILTERS = renderUI({
    selectInput("filters","Filters",choices = names(R),multiple = TRUE)
  })

  #this observe generates filters(selectInput widgets) dynamically, not important
  observe({
    req(input$filters)
    filter_names = input$filters

    # count how many filters I selected
    n = length(filter_names)     

    # to render n selectInput    
    lapply(1:n,function(x){
      output[[paste0("FILTER_",x)]] = renderUI({
        req(input$filters)
        div(
          selectInput(paste0("filter_",x),
                      paste0(filter_names[x]),
                      choices = unique(R[,filter_names[x]]),
                      multiple = TRUE,
                      selected = unique(R[,filter_names[x]])
                      ),
          actionButton(paste0("filter_all_",x),"(Un)Select All")
        )
      })
    })

    # this renders all the selectInput widgets
    output$FILTER_GROUP = renderUI({
      lapply(1:n, function(i){
        uiOutput(paste0("FILTER_",i))
      })
    })
  })
####################   issue begins ##################### 
  observe(

  n = length(input$filters)

  lapply(
    1:n,
    FUN = function(i){
      Filter = paste0("filter_",i)
      botton = paste0("filter_all_",i)

      observeEvent(botton,{
        NAME = input$filters[i]
        choices = unique(mtcars[,NAME])

        if (is.null(input[[Filter]])) {

          updateCheckboxGroupInput(
            session = session, inputId = Filter, selected = as.character(choices)
          )
        } else {
          updateCheckboxGroupInput(
            session = session, inputId = Filter, selected = ""
          )
        }
      })
    }
  )
  )
####################   issue ends #####################
})

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("FILTERS"),
  hr(),
  uiOutput("FILTER_GROUP")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Take a look to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40631788/shiny-observe-triggered-by-dynamicaly-generated-inputs/40643541#40643541

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has many problems, 1) You are evaluating the number of elements in a `selectInput` using `is.null` instead of `length`. 2) You are using  `updateCheckboxGroupInput` instead of `updateSelectInput`. 3) If you a put an observer inside another observer, you will be creating multiple observers for the same event. And 4) you have some missing `{}` in your last observer and a extra `)` in the server function.

The idea on the recommended [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40631788/shiny-observe-triggered-by-dynamicaly-generated-inputs/40643541#40643541) is to keep track of the last button clicked to avoid multiple observers. In your problem, in addition to have only one observer (and avoid nested observers), the idea is to know the `id` of the corresponding `selectInput` next to the `(Un)Select All` button. The goal is to only update that specific select input. In your code, the update will be applied to all the `selectInput`'s.

We need to add to each `actionButton` the id of the `selectInput` and the column name of the `mtcars` dataset associated with that `selectInput`. For that purpose, we can add the attributes: `data` for the id, and `name` for the column name. With JavaScript we can retrieve that attributes and send them back to the Server as the `input`'s `lastSelectId` and `lastSelectName` respectively.

Below is your code modified to have a JavaScript function to handle the `click` event for the selector `button`. Please note that we also need to wrap each `selectInput` and `actionButton` in a `div` with `class = "dynamicSI"` to distinguish from others buttons.

```R
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  R = mtcars[,c("cyl","am","carb","gear")]

  output$FILTERS = renderUI({
    selectInput("filters","Filters",choices = names(R),multiple = TRUE)
  })

  observe({

    req(input$filters)
    filter_names = input$filters

    # count how many filters I selected
    n = length(filter_names)     

    # to render n selectInput    
    lapply(1:n,function(x){
      output[[paste0("FILTER_",x)]] = renderUI({
        req(input$filters)
        div( class = "dynamicSI",
          selectInput(paste0("filter_",x),
                      paste0(filter_names[x]),
                      choices = unique(R[,filter_names[x]]),
                      multiple = TRUE,
                      selected = unique(R[,filter_names[x]])
                      ),
          actionButton(paste0("filter_all_",x),"(Un)Select All", 
                       data = paste0("filter_",x), # selectInput id
                       name = paste0(filter_names[x])) # name of column
        )
      })
    })

    output$FILTER_GROUP = renderUI({
      div(class="dynamicSI",
        lapply(1:n, function(i){
          uiOutput(paste0("FILTER_",i))
        })
      )

    })

  })


  observeEvent(input$lastSelect, {

    if (!is.null(input$lastSelectId)) {
      cat("lastSelectId:", input$lastSelectId, "\n")
      cat("lastSelectName:", input$lastSelectName, "\n")
    }  
    # selectInput id
    Filter = input$lastSelectId
    # column name of dataset, (label on select input)
    NAME = input$lastSelectName
    choices = unique(mtcars[,NAME])

    if (length(input[[Filter]]) == 0) {
      # in corresponding selectInput has no elements selected
      updateSelectInput(
        session = session, inputId = Filter, selected = as.character(choices)
      )
    } else {
      # has at least one element selected
      updateSelectInput(
        session = session, inputId = Filter, selected = ""
      )
    }

  })

  output$L = renderPrint({
    input$lastSelectId
  })
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script("$(document).on('click', '.dynamicSI button', function () {
                var id = document.getElementById(this.id).getAttribute('data');
                var name = document.getElementById(this.id).getAttribute('name');
                Shiny.onInputChange('lastSelectId',id);
                Shiny.onInputChange('lastSelectName',name);
                // to report changes on the same selectInput
                Shiny.onInputChange('lastSelect', Math.random());
                });"),  

  uiOutput("FILTERS"),
  hr(),
  uiOutput("FILTER_GROUP"),
  hr(),
  verbatimTextOutput("L")

)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: If we use the `dropdownButton` widget defined in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530142/drop-down-checkbox-input-in-shiny, any idea where we should put the `div(class = "dynamicSI",  ...)` statement in.

Comment: As close as possible to the action button to select all elements.

Comment: I updated my code. I tried several places to div class but none is working. Is the custom widget `dropdownButton` blocking the class defining...

Comment: It seems that it is more complex that just changing the `div` location. I have some ideas of how to solve that. Please open another question with your updated code, so we don't create a mess here.

Comment: Don't if my wording is OK but the link is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40759834/r-shiny-trigger-dynamically-created-without-using-nested-observe-function

Answer (score 1):

@Geovany

Updated

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)


dropdownButton <- function(label = "", status = c("default", "primary", "success", "info", "warning", "danger"), ..., width = NULL) {

  status <- match.arg(status)
  # dropdown button content
  html_ul <- list(
    class = "dropdown-menu",
    style = if (!is.null(width)) 
      paste0("width: ", validateCssUnit(width), ";"),
    lapply(X = list(...), FUN = tags$li, style = "margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;font-size:x-small")
  )
  # dropdown button apparence
  html_button <- list(
    class = paste0("btn btn-", status," dropdown-toggle"),
    type = "button", 
    `data-toggle` = "dropdown",
    style="font-size:x-small;width:135px"
    #    style="font-size:small;width:135px"

  )
  html_button <- c(html_button, list(label))
  html_button <- c(html_button, list(tags$span(class = "caret")))
  # final result
  tags$div(
    class = "dropdown",
    br(),
    do.call(tags$button, html_button),
    do.call(tags$ul, html_ul),
    tags$script(
      "$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
});")
  )
  }


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  R = mtcars[,c("cyl","am","carb","gear")]

  output$FILTERS = renderUI({
    selectInput("filters","Filters",choices = names(R),multiple = TRUE)
  })

  observe({

    req(input$filters)
    filter_names = input$filters

    # count how many filters I selected
    n = length(filter_names)     

    # to render n selectInput    
    lapply(1:n,function(x){
      output[[paste0("FILTER_",x)]] = renderUI({
        req(input$filters)
        div( class = "dynamicSI",

             dropdownButton(
               label = paste0(filter_names[x]), status ="default",width =50,

                   actionButton(inputId = paste0("filter_all_",x), label = "(Un)select all",
                                class="btn btn-primary btn-sm",
                                data = paste0("filter_",x),
                                name = paste(filter_names[x])
                   )

               ,
               checkboxGroupInput(paste0("filter_",x),"",
                                  choices = sort(unique(R[,filter_names[x]])),
                                  selected = unique(R[,filter_names[x]])
                                  )
             )


        )
      })
    })

    output$FILTER_GROUP = renderUI({
      div(class="dynamicSI",
          lapply(1:n, function(i){
            uiOutput(paste0("FILTER_",i))
          })
      )

    })

  })


  observeEvent(input$lastSelect, {

    if (!is.null(input$lastSelectId)) {
      cat("lastSelectId:", input$lastSelectId, "\n")
      cat("lastSelectName:", input$lastSelectName, "\n")
    }  
    # selectInput id
    Filter = input$lastSelectId
    # column name of dataset, (label on select input)
    NAME = input$lastSelectName
    choices = unique(mtcars[,NAME])

    if (length(input[[Filter]]) == 0) {
      # in corresponding selectInput has no elements selected
      updateSelectInput(
        session = session, inputId = Filter, selected = as.character(choices)
      )
    } else {
      # has at least one element selected
      updateSelectInput(
        session = session, inputId = Filter, selected = ""
      )
    }

  })

  output$L = renderPrint({
    input$lastSelectId
  })
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script("$(document).on('click', '.dynamicSI button', function () {
              var id = document.getElementById(this.id).getAttribute('data');
              var name = document.getElementById(this.id).getAttribute('name');
              Shiny.onInputChange('lastSelectId',id);
              Shiny.onInputChange('lastSelectName',name);
              // to report changes on the same selectInput
              Shiny.onInputChange('lastSelect', Math.random());
              });"),  

  uiOutput("FILTERS"),
  hr(),
  uiOutput("FILTER_GROUP"),
  hr(),
  verbatimTextOutput("L")

)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```