# Collect current user inputs and ignore/remove the previous inputs using R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I want to collect user inputs, and output them as a table/data frame within Shiny. Inspired by the post here ([Collect All user inputs throughout the Shiny App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41031584/collect-all-user-inputs-throughout-the-shiny-app)), I was able to do this but with some issues below. Here I have attached the example code, where I intend to collect the user input using the reactive textInput box. The number of textInput boxes is according to the user input for "Number of box".  The output table looks fine when I kept increasing the "Number of box", such as I increased the number of boxes from 1 to 2 (see attached screenshot 1 and 2). However, when I changed the number of boxes from 2 back to 1, the output table still showed the previous results "textBox2  the second input" (see screenshot 3). My question is how to remove this previous input ("textBox2  the second input") and only print out the current user input. Thanks!

**Example code**

```
library(shiny)
ui <- basicPage(
  fluidRow(column(6,
           numericInput("nbox", "Number of box", value = 1, 
                        min = 1))),
  fluidRow(column(6,style='padding:0px;',
                  wellPanel(
                    uiOutput("textInputBox"))), 
           column(6, style='padding:0px;',
                  tableOutput('show_inputs')))
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  
  output$textInputBox <- renderUI({
    num <- as.integer(input$nbox)
    lapply(1:num, function(i) {
      textInput(paste0("textBox", i),
                label = paste0("textBox", i))
      })
    })

  AllInputs <- reactive({
    myvalues <- NULL
    for(i in 1:length(names(input))){
      myvalues <- as.data.frame(rbind(myvalues,
                                      (cbind(names(input)[i],input[[names(input)[i]]]))))
    }
    names(myvalues) <- c("User input variable","User input value")
    myvalues
  })
  
  output$show_inputs <- renderTable({
    AllInputs()
    })
  
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Screen shot (1,2,3 in order)**
[image: screenshot_1]
[image: screenshot_2]
[image: screenshot_3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created inputs are not deleted when a new `renderUI` is called, so there is no solution this way.

A workaround is to use a counter (like the one previously used to create the input) and use it to rebuild the names:

```
AllInputs <- reactive({
    num <- as.integer( input$nbox )
    my_names <- paste0("textBox", 1:num)
    all_values <- stack( reactiveValuesToList(input) )
    myvalues <- all_values[ all_values$ind %in% c("nbox", my_names), 
                            c(2, 1)]
    names(myvalues) <- c("User input variable","User input value")
    myvalues
})
```

Note the use of `reactiveValuesToList` to replace the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This works well for the example code. The rebuild seems a little painful especially I have a bunch of user inputs. But I am going to apply this to my Shiny and see if it will work. The reason I used loop is because some of the input variables have different length (i.e., matrix input) than others.

Comment: I was able to apply this to my code although this is really not efficient when there are a lot of variables. But thank you for explaining the concept here for me. I accepted your answer. @HubertL