# Update multiple shiny apps inputs with different input widget types

Tags: r, shiny, shinystore

I have designed a Shiny app with two action buttons, `Save` and `Clear`. When users click `Save`, the input values will be stored using local storage of the web browser. When users click `Clear`, the inputs and local storage would be cleaned.

These functionalities involves updating multiple inputs with `update...Input`. In this example, I have three inputs all with different widget types. I can specifically write them one by one, which works fine. However, I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to achieve this, such as using `for loop` or `lapply`. From this post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41061114/7669809), it seems like I can use `reactiveValuesToList` to get all inputs. The real challenge to me is how to dynamically call different `update...Input` functions for the associated input widget types?

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

```
### This script creates an example of the shinystore package

# Load packages
library(shiny)
library(shinyStore)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("shinyStore Example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
      initStore("store", "shinyStore-ex1"),
      textInput(inputId = "Text1", label = "Enter some texts")
    ),
    mainPanel = mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        numericInput(inputId = "Number1", label = "Enter a number", value = NA),
        sliderInput(inputId = "Slider1", label = "Pick a number", min = 0, max = 100, value = 50),
        actionButton("save", "Save", icon("save")),
        actionButton("clear", "Clear", icon("stop"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    if (input$save <= 0){
      updateTextInput(session, inputId = "Text1", value = isolate(input$store)$Text1)
      updateNumericInput(session, inputId = "Number1", value = isolate(input$store)$Number1)
      updateSliderInput(session, inputId = "Slider1", value = isolate(input$store)$Slider1)
    }
    updateStore(session, name = "Text1", isolate(input$Text1))
    updateStore(session, name = "Number1", isolate(input$Number1))
    updateStore(session, name = "Slider1", isolate(input$Slider1))
  })
  
  observe({
    if (input$clear > 0){
      updateTextInput(session, inputId = "Text1", value = NA)
      updateNumericInput(session, inputId = "Number1", value = NA)
      updateSliderInput(session, inputId = "Slider1", value = 50)
      
      updateStore(session, name = "Text1", value = NA)
      updateStore(session, name = "Number1", value = NA)
      updateStore(session, name = "Slider1", value = 50)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no generic `updateInput` function in `shiny`. It is still possible to build a wrapper that identifies a certain name to a certain input type, but that will also require to know which argument is allowed or no. For example, `updateActionButton` doesn't have `value` or `choices` as an argument so we'll need numerous if statements.

A possible workaround is to take advantage of `renderUI` and directly pass the stored values. The only downside is that some functions like `SliderInput` throw an error when some arguments are NULL, so an if statement is needed to appoint a default value for the first time the app runs. Alternatively a mock app can be executed once to only fill the first values.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyStore)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
    initStore("store", "shinyStore-ex1"),
    uiOutput('ui_all'))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    

    output$ui_all <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        headerPanel("shinyStore Example"),
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
                textInput(inputId = "Text1", label = "Enter some texts",value = input$store$Text1)
            ),
            mainPanel = mainPanel(
                fluidRow(
                    numericInput(inputId = "Number1", label = "Enter a number", value = input$store$Number1),
                    sliderInput(inputId = "Slider1", label = "Pick a number", min = 0, max = 100, value = if(is.null(input$store$Slider1)){50} else{input$store$Slider1}),
                    actionButton("save", "Save", icon("save")),
                    actionButton("clear", "Clear", icon("stop"))
                )
            )
        ))
    })
    
     
    input_nms <- map(c('Text', 'Number', 'Slider'), ~str_c(.x, 1:1)) %>%
                    reduce(c)
    
    #or if every type of input is repeteated n different times.
    # input_nms <- map2(c('Text', 'Number', 'Slider'), c(n1, n2, n3), ~str_c(.x, 1:.y)) %>%
    #     reduce(c)
    
        
    observeEvent(input$save, {
       input_nms %>% 
            walk(~updateStore(session = session, name = .x, value =  isolate(input[[.x]])))
            session$reload() #to force the UI to render again with the new values
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$clear, {
        input_nms %>% 
            walk2(c(NA, NA, 50), ~updateStore(session = session, name = .x, value = .y))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```